# Sequlize js auto increment primary key is passing a null value

Tags: sequelize.js

In my **restaurant_images.js model**

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const restaurant_images = sequelize.define('restaurant_images', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    image_path: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    restaurant_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  }, {});
  restaurant_images.associate = function (models) {
    restaurant_images.belongsTo(models.restaurants, {
      foreignKey: 'restaurant_id'
    })
  };
  return restaurant_images;
};
```

In my **controller**

```
const setImages = await db.restaurant_images.bulkCreate(images);
```

Here **images** is an array of objects, which is each object has `image_path` and `restaurant_id`

This generates a query like this.

```
`restaurant_images` (`id`,`image_path`,`restaurant_id`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,'https://xxx.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/',31,'2018-09-25 05:32:06','2018-09-25 05:32:06')
```

Here It supposed to pass `default` for the id column. But it pass `null` for the id column.

and I try to log the output of

```
const setImages = await db.restaurant_images.bulkCreate(images);
```

it gives me

```
SET IMAGES [ restaurant_images {
    dataValues:
     { id: 146,
       image_path: 'https://igateeatme.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hkjkjkj//Screenshot%20%284%29.png',
       restaurant_id: 36,
       createdAt: 2018-09-25T08:27:22.803Z,
       updatedAt: 2018-09-25T08:27:22.803Z },
```

it assigns an id. But the only problem is it doesn't insert that id.
It doesn't insert anything to the `restaurant_images` table.

Why could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

> I think , the table is not created via Sequlize sync , and you might
>   have created it by self and forgot to make primary key when creating
>   table ,
>
> If that's the case , your model definition want effect your table
>   until unless you run `model.sync()` , what it will do is make relative
>   changes to the DB as per your model definition.
>
> **Model definition want be affected to your real DB Table untill unless you run `model.sync()`**

You can remove , as Sequlize js will create primary key for you by default , if you run `model.sync()`

```
id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I attached the bulkCreate response also. It doesn't gives me any error for the catch block but it doesn't insert anything to the db. and how do I run model.sync() inside my restaurant_images model?

Comment: restaurant_images.sync();

Comment: in restaurant_images.js model.

Comment: Could you please future explain my model's structure is something like this ```const restaurant_images = sequlize.define('restaurant_images',{},{})```  Where do I put sync()?

Comment: try it before , `return restaurant_images;`

Comment: "you might have created it by self" - I'm using migrations and did a seed with an id with a number, to use it later in some tests. After that `autoIncrement` was not working anymore. I'm not sure if this answer fits the original question, but it worked for me! Thank you!